# jquery delegate's event need ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).delegate('.text','click',function(){
       //do something...
```

I have a page required to do something when document ready, this page also use jquery load append data from another page. I wish this script apply to all child element include the page load in.

my problem is i need the delegate's event, something like ready not click.

Comment: you need to make use of the `load()` methods success handler

Comment: Is there any special reason to use delegate's event ?? You can use load() method as Arun said and you can also use **jQuery.ajax()**